# Class/Object/Method Organization Confusion

Tags: java, class, object, methods, arraylist

I'm beginning at Java, so the thinking behind organizing my code so it's cohesive isn't really coming naturally yet.  Essentially, I have an ArrayList that has a method that populates it, another that shuffles it, and then a tester program to see if that even worked.  My problem is organizing it.  From my experience methods can't really see what's in each other, so I have it organized like so:

```
Class
    ArrayList (named al)

    Tester Method

    Shuffle Method

    ArrayList Population Method
```

My trouble is thusly; how do I, in the tester method, make the ArrayList undergo the actions defined for it in the methods.  I've worked with Constructors and Objects, but they don't really seem to apply at least is what I've done so far.  I thought it would be something like

```
al.Shuffle();
```

But it threw errors all over the place.  Does anyone have any insight?

EDIT: as requested, here's the code

```
package deckofcards;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Deck{
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    //test method
    public void main(String[] args){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         al.Deck();
         //didn't get any further, that threw a "cannot find symbol" error
         }
    }
    private void Shuffle(){
         Collections.shuffle(al);
    }
    private void Deck(){
         al.add(0, "Ace of Spades");
         //and this goes on for a deck of cards
    }
 }
```

Comment: make your arraylist a field of the class and do all kind of operations with it inside your methods?

Comment: Sorry, I can't have insights about unposted errors for unposted code.

Answer (score 1):

Define another class that extends `ArrayList`

```
public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<Object> {

    public MyArrayList(){
        super();
    }

    public MyArrayList shuffle(MyArrayList mal){
        Collections.shuffle(mal);
        return mal;
    }

}
```

And then define everything as `MyArrayList`. This will basically be the exact same class as `ArrayList` with extra functionality you want.

---

```
public class Deck {
    static MyArrayList al = new MyArrayList();
        //test method
        public static void main(String[] args){
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             Deck();
             al = al.shuffle(al);
             //didn't get any further, that threw a "cannot find symbol" error

             for(Object i : al)
                 System.out.println(i);
        }
        private static void Deck(){
             al.add(0, "Ace of Spades");
             al.add(1, "1");
             al.add(2, "2");
             al.add(3, "3");
             //and this goes on for a deck of cards
        }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea that was even possible, I'll have to look up how to do that

Comment: The problem I'm running into is the `al.shuffle(al);` is giving "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method Shuffle(ArrayList<String>)
  location: variable al of type ArrayList<String>"

Comment: Did you run my code? It's a complete compilable project.

Answer (score 1):

In Your components, the class is the main component that holds the rest of your component, then the methods is a task or action that the class can do.

`ArrayList` is a data structure that holds a data with a specific structure. which  the class can use it.

so you orginization could look like this:

```
class MyClass {

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {//Tester Method is the main method, because the execution began from here
    }


    private void populate() {
        //
    }        

    private void shuffle() {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: so do the private void Deck() method outside of the class?

Comment: you can't have a method out side a class, because method is a behavior or action that class can do.

Comment: ok, I currently have my code in a similar format, (see above, edited with full code), but now in the Tester method, how do I then invoke the methods upon the arraylist, i.e. al.Method(); didn't work